# A way to change Bootstrap border widths?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap and [Bootstrap Live Customizer](http://bootstrap-live-customizer.com/) to build a theme for a new site. One feature seems like it may be missing. I'm not sure how change the border width on any elements. Is there a way to change this globally, with or without Bootstrap Live Customizer? Or do I have to append my own CSS for this? Fairly new to Bootstrap, BTW.

Comment: i think best practice is to write your own css file. bad practice is to attach the bootstrap css file, because you have to redo it every time you update your libraries.

Comment: Are you saying it's bad to use bootstrap?

Comment: No. He's saying not to modify bootstrap. Add your own css file and put your site-specific entries in there.

Comment: i say to manipulate a framework u use is a bad idea. bootstrap is a very powerfull framework, and i love it.

Comment: @DanielH if normal css declation does not work, you simply have to use !important. e.g. `border-width: 3px !important;` in your own css file

Comment: @TypeSource, you guys are aware that Bootstrap Live Customizer lets you save and reimport your variables, right? It's pretty powerful.

Comment: @TypedSource yes, use !important